# How to extract number of minutes from time sentence in java? e.g xx hrs xx mins

Tags: java

I know the title is confusing but I couldn't think of a better one.

Say I've got a string, which could look something like `([number] hr(s)) [number] min(s)`

Some examples of that would be `1 min`, `15 mins`, `3 hrs 50 mins`, `1 hr 15 mins`, `4 hrs 1 min` etc

How do I efficiently extract from such strings the number of minutes? I want it to take into account hours too, so `3 hrs 50 mins` would yield `230`. The only thing I can think of is doing a lot of if clauses and using regex but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: how about splitting the `String` with a space ?

Comment: You should take some time to check out the many methods provided by the [`String` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). You might just come up with something yourself...

Comment: What would you expect for `3 hrs 50 mins` - `50` or `230`?

Comment: The regex `(\d+)\s+mins?` will capture all your examples, provided that you're only interested in the fractional portion of the hour. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to implement that in Java.

Comment: can you add the test input and expected output???

Comment: Sure, basically I want the number of minutes for a period of time

`3 hrs 50 mins` would be `230`  . I want it to take into account hours too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A different approach offering you more flexibility:

```
public long getMinutes(String input) {
    input = input.toLowerCase()
                 .replaceAll("mins?", "M") 
                 .replaceAll("hrs?", "H")
                 .replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    Duration d = Duration.parse("PT" + input);
    return d.toMinutes();
}
```

([Working sample on ideone](https://ideone.com/womLhM))

Outputs for your sample data:

```
1 min: 1
15 mins: 15
3 hrs 50 mins: 230
1 hr 15 mins: 75
4 hrs 1 min: 241
```

The basic idea is to convert your input to a string that is supported by Java's [`Duration#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) method (`PT<hours>H<minutes>M`) and then let that work out the magic. You end up with a `Duration` object that provides various ways of working with it afterwards.

Note that this prints `230` for `3 hrs 50 mins`. If you require only the `50` then a simple regular expression would be the easier way.

(In production code I would merge the various `replaceAll` calls into one and replace the `toLowerCase` with case-insensitive pattern matching for better efficiency. It is left here explicitly for better understandability.)

Comment: Great use of `Duration`. Small improvement suggestion: use `toLowerCase()` on the input string before replacing anything. This way this algo will also support syntax like `Hrs`, `HRS` or `Mins`.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak: Done, thanks! ItamarG3: Thank you as well - I went one step further and aligned the dots.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a RegEx solution:

```
((\d+)\s*(hours|hrs|hr|h)\s*)?(\d\d?)\s*(minutes|mins|min|m)
```

Number of minutes:

```
minutes = $1 * 60 + $4
```

Rules:

- you must provide mins, even if it's a full hour
- you can omit the hours, so `1 min` is equivalent to `0 hrs 1 min`
- if the pattern doesn't match, the format is invalid
- for best results use with case insensitive matching (usually `i` option)

Playground: https://regex101.com/r/u8BMtl/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, hope it helps.

```
String time="3 hrs 50 mins";
    String[] array = time.split(" ");
    int minutes = 0;
    if(array.length>2){  // if it has minute and hour content 
        minutes = Integer.parseInt(array[0])*60 + Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
    } else{  // if time has only minute content
        minutes = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

if your time is X hrs Y min

```
String time = "3 hrs 10 min";
String[] parts = time.split(" ");
int total = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
```

this wait it will give you the string of hours, multiply by 60 minutes and add minutes. If you only need minutes, just take parts[2]

you could use Regex too

Comment: Apart from the fact that this code wouldn't compile, it won't work if only mins are given

Comment: This code seems like it is coded in an hybrid of python and Java. Java is **statically typed**!!

Comment: updated ! was thinking of type and forgot to write it. 
Thanks for the comment
and only giving him one example, I think he could be able to find the answer with the doc, searching for split